# gevent monkey patching order

Tags: python, gevent, monkeypatching

At work we're using gevent to create some asynchronous servers, and there's some debate about when to perform monkey patching in relation to other modules. The gevent documentation shows things like this:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_socket()
import socket
```

Where the monkey patching happens before the library modules have been imported.

However, my manager feels the order of monkey patching should be this:

```
import socket
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_socket()
```

Where monkey patching is called after the library module is imported. Which makes it look like monkey patching sees the socket module has been imported, and patches it at that point.

I've found some discussions that say do it one way, and others that say to do it the other. My own simple testing seems to say it doesn't matter. I am seeking opinions on this, with some clear reasons why, or references that would say why.

Answer (score 1):

As the current maintainer of gevent, I will point to [the documentation](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#beyond-sockets) which specifically says ([multiple times](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#patching)) that the recommended way to monkey-patch is to do it *as early as possible*, and preferably *before* any other imports.

Now, with most standard library modules you can get away with monkey-patching after they're imported. But third-party libraries are not necessarily safe that way. In general, it's just safer and reduces trouble to monkey-patch ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for the "smack upside the head", I've read that documentation a couple of times, and was still confused because of the examples I've seen around the net that do it otherwise. Should have trusted the docs. :)

Comment: Hi Jason,
Please clarify what is wrong with

    (Python 3.5.2 on linux)

    **from gevent.monkey import patch_all; is_module_patched;  patch_all();  import socket;  is_module_patched(socket)**
 =>  _False_

Comment: `is_module_patched(modname)` takes a module *name* not the module itself.

Comment: The docs never justify their "as early as possible" recommendation. They tell only "if you patch it after X, Y or Z weird stuff may occur". Could you please tell why we should patch "as early as possible" instead of "before we do any of X, Y, Z"?

Comment: There are numerous ways that things can go wrong, and it's much easier to say "do it early" rather than enumerating all the possible things that must not have happened before patching. As just one example, if any module has already done 'from socket import socket', by the time you patch, things will go wrong. In general, you can't, and don't need to, know if a module does 'import socket' or 'from socket import socket' in its internal implementation but only one of them would work correctly if you patched after importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the source code (see bellow) `patch_socket` calls `patch_module` which imports the `socket` module for you.

```
def patch_module(name, items=None):
    gevent_module = getattr(__import__('gevent.' + name), name)
    module_name = getattr(gevent_module, '__target__', name)
    module = __import__(module_name)
    if items is None:
        items = getattr(gevent_module, '__implements__', None)
        if items is None:
            raise AttributeError('%r does not have __implements__' % gevent_module)
    for attr in items:
        patch_item(module, attr, getattr(gevent_module, attr))
    return module
```

See that in `gevent` repository on GitHub.

So, you don't need to import socket at all (unless you use it of course).